# Searching and sorting a file in Python

Tags: python, file, datetime, syntax-error

I am trying to set up a script that looks at an indivdual file containing things like IP address and date. I want to extract all the data that is older than 365 days and have a text file to look at. I keep running in to road blocks with syntax errors etc.

I have tried changing

```
day = eval(line) to day = str(line) but I get
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to str
```

```py
#!/bin/env python

from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

limit = datetime.datetime.now() +  timedelta(days=365)
with open('filename') as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        day = eval(line)
        if day > limit:
            break
formatted_dates = [(item[0], item[1].strptime("%d/%m/%y"), item[2]) for item in sorted_dates]
for date in formatted_dates:
    print ('{}: {}'.format(date))
```

I want to get a new file that reads:

128.xxx.xxx.xx [%d %m %y] from oldest to newest.

I keep getting:

```
File "./scrpitpyth.py", line 9, in <module>
    day = eval(line)
  File "<string>", line 1
  128.xxx.xxx.xx - - [02/Feb/2016:15:00:26 -0700] 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The data I am trying to parse looks like:

128.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [20/Mar/2017:09:54:03 -0600] "POST /work/labor/ HTTP/1.1"

128.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [23/Mar/2017:09:54:03 -0600] "GET /work/ HTTP/1.1" 200

128.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [24/Mar/2017:09:56:02 -0600] "GET /work/view/laborcats

Comment: As mentioned in the answers below `eval()` is the issue, but to help with a suggestion, could you provide some of the example text file you are trying to parse?

Comment: Just added them

Comment: It cannot be stressed enough: **Never use `eval()`**. Especially on untrusted input.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but my karma is too low.

Using the eval function is typically not recommended since it just executes whatever string is passed. In this case you are trying to run the string `128.xxx.xxx.xx - - [02/Feb/2016:15:00:26 -0700]` as a python command. Since this is not valid python you get a failure.

To solve this problem I would recommend using the strptime funciton from the datetime library to convert the timestamp string into a datetime object, you can then do your time filtering with this object.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` attempts to execute a string as python code. The lines you're presenting to it are not legitimate python code, which is why the `eval` fails.

You would probably want to use a regular expression to extract the date, see the re module for details

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

by way of an example, the following pattern matches dates in the format given in your sample line:

```
>>> pat = re.compile("\d+/\w+/\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+ -?\d+")
>>> pat.search(date_str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104982e00>
>>> _.group()
'02/Feb/2016:15:00:26 -0700'
>>>
```